# How to change commands, math mode

Tags: math-mode, integral

So, that's a silly question, but, nevertheless, I'll ask it. Thing is, my integral signs are quite small, so I used the package  `bigints`. Two problems:

(i) How do I write multiple integrals using that command?

(ii) Is there a way to make the usual command  `int` to "be" that one?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: May I ask what font you are using? Some OpenType fonts have scalable integrals that can be used (if you use luatex or xetex).

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delay. I'm using the americal maths society fonts, the package ```amsfonts```.

Comment: it would help if you showed an example, the integral is available in two sizes, one for inline math and one for display, are you using the display version?